# textOffset of an element in html5

Tags: javascript, html

i need to create a rect element using the height and width of the text 'Popcorn'.

The Rect is shown as a tooltip. Each time when the mouse moves, the text get changed and again i am calculating the text height and width to create a new rect by adding text element with the changed text to document as below.

```
 var textelement = document.createElement('text');      
  textelement.innerHTML = 'Popcorn', // text get changed on mouse move

  document.body.appendChild(textelement);
  var bounds = { width: textelement .offsetWidth, height: textelement .offsetHeight};  
  $(textObj).remove();
```

Because of this my performance is very slow, as a element('textelement') is added and removed from the DOM each time when the mouse is move.

Is there any another way to calculate the text height and width without touching the DOM.

Thanks In advance

Comment: Could you add your HTML and CSS?

Comment: Nothing here in html, just added a div element and binded the mousemove events.... on moving the mouse over the div, a rect is displayed based text height and width